# How to find the serial number of removable devices using C program

Tags: c, linux, usb, usb-drive

I am using the bash script to get the serial number of the removable device like pen drive for my another application.
Is it possible to do in native C can someone convert this bash to C.

```
#!/bin/bash
for C in `ls /sys/block/`; do 
    RE=`cat /sys/block/$C/removable`
        if [ $RE == "1" ] ;then 
            #VENDOR=`/bin/udevadm info --name=/dev/$C | grep ID_VENDOR=|awk -F"=" ' { print $2}'`
            #MODEL=`/bin/udevadm info --name=/dev/$C | grep ID_MODEL=|awk -F"=" ' { print $2}'`
            #SERIAL=`/bin/udevadm info --name=/dev/$C | grep SERIAL_SHORT|awk -F"=" ' { print $2}'`
            #echo $VENDOR-$MODEL"-"$SERIAL #print as per your taste
            USB_SERIAL=`/bin/udevadm info --name=/dev/$C | grep ID_SERIAL=|awk -F"=" ' { print $2}'|awk -F"-" ' { print $1}'`
            echo  $USB_SERIAL #or just the default one
        fi 
done
```

I  dont want to use system calls. want pure C program

Comment: The standard C library does not include functions for this; you'll have to rely on OS-specific code that does exactly what you do above--read from the /sys/ file(s).

Comment: Stackoverflow is more for asking specific questions about programming. If you would like someone to write you some software based on your specifications, try a freelancing site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key challenge here is, since you don't want to use `system()`, to emulate the working of `udevadm info`. The following program does this (at least on my system) by reading the information from `/run/udev/data/bMAJOR:MINOR`, where *MAJOR* and *MINOR* are the device numbers we get from `/sys/block/NAME/dev`, where *NAME* is the block device name.

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    struct dirent *entry;           // read thru the entries in "/sys/block"
    for (DIR *dirp = opendir("/sys/block"); entry = readdir(dirp); )
    if (entry->d_type == DT_LNK)    // the relevant files are symbolic links
    {
        char path[277];
        sprintf(path, "/sys/block/%s/removable", entry->d_name);
        FILE *fp = fopen(path, "r"); if (!fp) return perror(path), 1;
        int re;                     // read the /sys/block/%s/removable flag
        fscanf(fp, "%d", &re), fclose(fp);
        if (re)
        {                           // read the device's MAJOR:MINOR numbers
            sprintf(path, "/sys/block/%s/dev", entry->d_name);
            fp = fopen(path, "r"); if (!fp) return perror(path), 1;
            fscanf(fp, "%s", path+sprintf(path, "/run/udev/data/b")),
            fclose(fp);
            fp = fopen(path, "r"); if (!fp) return perror(path), 1;
            char USB_serial[NAME_MAX];  // scan the udev/data for ID_SERIAL=
            while (fgets(path, sizeof path, fp))
                if (sscanf(path, "E:ID_SERIAL=%[^-]", USB_serial) > 0)
                    puts(USB_serial);
            fclose(fp);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent substitute for my bash.